# Require two factor authentication on Facebook

Tags: facebook, security, passwords, google-authenticator

I'd like to set up 2 factor authentication on Facebook that uses my phone. In Facebook's security settings I've gotten to "Set Up a Third Party App to Generate Codes". It gave me a QR code to scan which I succesfully added to Google Authenticator but when I sign into Facebook it never asks for it and doesn't require it. I also tried Facebook's [Code Generator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.codemonkey.otpgeneratorapp&hl=en), but when I click add it doesn't launch any camera app.

How can I have my Facebook account prompt me for a changing password in addition to my regular one?

Comment: If you are not stuck with third party app, you can use your mobile number to active to two-factor authentication.

Comment: @serenesat how and what do you mean? Are you talking about receiving a text message each time?

Comment: Yes, receiving a code as text message whenever you login from new device/browser.